# Make R.pipe work with a Promise?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

### Background

I have a simple code that composes functions to print `Hello Mars!`:

```
var greeting = () => "Hello ";
var dbQuery = str => Promise.resolve( `${str} Mars` );

var phrase = R.pipeP(
    greeting,
    dbQuery, 
    R.flip( R.concat )("!")
);

phrase();
```

### Problem

I am using `pipeP` because `dbQuery` returns a Promise. I am under the impression that `pipeP` could work if I converted my entire code to promises, but **I really do want to avoid that**.

My idea was to something something like `flatMap`, aka `chain` in Ramda, but that doesn't work either.

### Question

How can I make this code work without converting everything into a Promise?

[**A MWE can be found here**](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20greeting%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%22Hello%20%22%3B%0Avar%20dbQuery%20%3D%20str%20%3D%3E%20Promise.resolve%28%20%60%24%7Bstr%7D%20Mars%60%20%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20phrase%20%3D%20R.pipeP%28%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%2C%0A%20%20%20%20dbQuery%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.flip%28%20R.concat%20%29%28%22%21%22%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aphrase%28%29%3B)

Comment: How about just writing it normally, without Ramda?

Comment: Check discussion in [this thread](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/2417) - as well as discussions linked in there. In short, Ramda team sees `pipeP` (and `composeP`) as old way of doing things.

Comment: @raina77ow That could work if `greeting` was a Promise. However, it isn't. When the first value in the pipe is not a composition, how could you make it work?

Comment: You want to compose a nullary function with an action that returns a `Promise`. This just doesn't work and Ramda is right to complain.

Comment: I know why Ramda complains. I never said Ramda was wrong. I made that clear in my post and even suggest fixes that i don't like.

Comment: Well, then don't compose what can't be composed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are dealing with Promise/Task/Future, there's no avoiding having to handle asynchronous data and program flow

> How can I make this code work without converting everything into a Promise?

By *everything*, do you mean this part?

```
// ...
phrase();
```

For the same reason the ternary operator `?:` forces you to include *both* branches of the conditional, asynchronous calls expect you to handle both the successful *and* the erroneous branches of the Promise/Task/Future

```
// ...
phrase().then(onSuccess, onError);
```

Of course there's nothing stopping you from doing

```
const main = () =>
  phrase().then(console.log, console.error)

main()
```

And as [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow) mentions, pipeP (and composeP) are [not recommended](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/2417). We can fix your program by adding a simple `then` function which is easily inserted in a normal `pipe` (or `compose`) sequence of functions

```js
const greeting = () => "Hello ";
const dbQuery = str => Promise.resolve( `${str} Mars` );

const then = R.curry((f, p) => p.then(f))

const phrase = R.pipe(
  greeting,
  dbQuery,
  then(R.flip(R.concat)('!'))
);

phrase().then(console.log, console.error);
// Hello Mars!
// => { Promise 'Hello Mars!' }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: That `then` helper function is something I would expect to see in Ramda. Your example explained all I needed to know. Thanks !

Comment: Somehow the Ramda team got sidetracked on this, but we do [plan on addding](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1906) it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Weren't you going to deprecate `pipeP` anyway in favor of using Futures?

Comment: We were going to deprecate `pipeP` because we prefer lawful types like `Futures`, and we were going to add `then` to allow Promise-users to still get a reasonable experience.  We're still planning on this, but we've been slow to move lately.

Comment: What if you want to add more functions to the chain? Like `const phrase = R.pipe(greeting, dbQuery, then(R.flip(R.concat)('!')), R.concat('!'));`. Will you always need to use `then` after dbQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following helper function below which should solve your problem.  It deals with promise and non-promise data equally. It also checks for arrays with promises being returned and, if so, handles them with `Promise.all`. As expected, its final result will be a promise.

```
function asyncPipe(...funcs){
  const reducer = async (val, func) => func(await (Array.isArray(val) ? Promise.all(val): val));
  return async val => await R.reduce(reducer, val, funcs)
}
```

Here is how to use `asyncPipe` for your original code problem:

```
function asyncPipe(...funcs){
  const reducer = async (val, func) => func(await (Array.isArray(val) ? Promise.all(val): val));
  return async val => await R.reduce(reducer, val, funcs)
}

var greeting = () => "Hello ";
var dbQuery = str => Promise.resolve( `${str} Mars` );

var phrase = asyncPipe(
    greeting,
    dbQuery, 
    R.flip( R.concat )("!")
);

phrase().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramda now includes then and otherwise functions, so best to use these:

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#andThen

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#otherwise